# Remove spam SQL Injection from some tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, sql-injection

I have a SQL Server table that is used to populate a website

The website has been attacked, probably using some SQL injection technique and many columns in this table (text columns) have some HTML into it, usually like `<div>some stuff and some links</div>`.

I simply want to remove everything after the first `<div>` using:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyField = REPLACE (MyField,
                       SUBSTRING(MyField, CHARINDEX('<', MyField), LEN(MyField)), '')
WHERE MyField LIKE '%<%'
```

It does work great on `nvarchar` and `char` columns, but it doesn't work on `nvarchar(max)` columns. I get this error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10, Row 1
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>
> Msg 3621, Level 0, State 0, Row 1
>   The statement has been terminated.

What should I do to remove this stuff from `nvarchar(max)` columns?

Answer (score 1):

You should subtract to `LEN(MyField)` the position of `'<'` in your string:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyField = REPLACE (MyField,
                       SUBSTRING(MyField, CHARINDEX('<', MyField), LEN(MyField)-CHARINDEX('<',MyField)-1), '')
WHERE MyField LIKE '%<%'
```

I also suggest you to search for the `'<div>'` substring to avoid loosing data that starts with '<' but isn't spam.

Comment: actually, end of the string doesn't matter, it can be anything up to 8000 chars with no problem...

also, I am sure there's no other "<" char in the field, most are city, region, country names...

Comment: You should try to select Len( ...substring inside of the replace function... ) and check if the Len is always < then the max